# Merging list of dataframes by name of list object

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I have a dataframe `df`

```
structure(list(X = 1:12, id = structure(c(2L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("B12", "B7", "C2", 
"C9", "D3", "E2", "E6", "R4", "T2", "T3", "T7", "U9"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(42L, 45L, 83L, 59L, 49L, 46L, 52L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I have split the people in the above dataframe into a list of 3 matrices called `list_mat`

```
list(Blue_Banana = structure(c("B7", "E6", "D3", "C9"), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("target", "partner"))), Gold_Apple = structure(c("C2", 
"B12", "E2", "R4"), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("target", "partner"))), Blue_Orange = structure(c("T2", 
"T3", "T7", "U9"), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("target", 
"partner"))))
```

I would like to group the matrices based on keywords in the names of their matrix objects which can be found with

```
names(list_mat)
```

I then use a function from the `igraph` package to calculate in-degree

```
list_graph= lapply(list_mat, graph_from_edgelist, directed=TRUE)
cent_list= lapply(list_graph, centr_degree, mode="in")
```

To get the actual in-degree scores I'll use the first matrix object inside `list_mat` as an example

```
cent_list[[1]]$res
```

To get the ID of who the indegree scores refer to I'll again just use the first matrix inside `list_mat` as an example

```
V(list_graph[[1]])$name
```

I want the in-degree scores of all the values in the matrices inside `list_mat` that contain the string "Blue" in their name to be matched with their ID in the original dataframe `df` and this will create a column called "Blue" that contains the in-degree scores of the ID's in those matrices. I then want to do the same thing with all the matrices that have "Gold" in the name of the matrix objects inside `list_mat` (there's only one matrix with "Gold" in the name) The final output will look something like the picture at the bottom, but the numbers may be different.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly there are multiple ways to achieve this; here's one. First,

```
(blues <- grep("Blue", names(list_graph)))
# [1] 1 3
```

determines which graphs are about "Blue". Then

```
(db <- degree(Reduce(`+`, list_graph[blues]), mode = "in"))
# B7 D3 E6 C9 T2 T7 T3 U9 
#  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1 
(do <- degree(Reduce(`+`, list_graph[-blues]), mode = "in"))
#  C2  E2 B12  R4 
#   0   1   0   1
```

are the in-degrees of the two groups. To insert this into `df` we may use base R's `merge` as in

```
merge(merge(df, data.frame(Blue = db), by.x = "id", by.y = "row.names", all.x = TRUE),
      data.frame(Gold = do), by.x = "id", by.y = "row.names", all.x = TRUE)
#     id  X age Blue   Gold
# 1  B12  6  46   NA      0
# 2   B7  1  42    0     NA
# 3   C2  5  49   NA      0
# 4   C9  4  59    1     NA
# 5   D3  3  83    1     NA
# 6   E2  7  52   NA      1
# 7   E6  2  45    0     NA
# 8   R4  8  23   NA      1
# 9   T2  9  24    0     NA
# 10  T3 10  25    0     NA
# 11  T7 11  26    1     NA
# 12  U9 12  27    1     NA
```

which gives a result with NA's, but actually that may be more adequate as in this way it's clear to which group the row belongs. Otherwise, e.g., in rows 9 and 10 it wouldn't be clear.

---

More generally, we may do

```
keywords <- c("Blue", "Gold", "Red", "Purple") # Assuming all those are present
for(k in keywords) {
  idx <- grep(k, names(list_graph))
  deg <- degree(Reduce(`+`, list_graph[idx]), mode = "in")
  df <- merge(df, data.frame(deg), by.x = "id", by.y = "row.names", all.x = TRUE)
  names(df)[ncol(df)] <- k
}
```

One part worth explaining is

```
Reduce(`+`, list_graph[idx])
```

Instead of combining different "Blue" degrees from different graphs, I first combine graphs, as in `g1 + g2` (yes, it works), where the resulting graph has two components `g1` and `g2`, and then compute degrees of this super-graph. Now `Reduce` allows to sum up in this way any number of graphs, i.e., it does `g1 + g2 + ... + gk` for all the graphs in `list_graph[idx]`.

Comment: @M76, right, just got mixed up with the names. Fixed. By the way, I'm assuming that each graph is either Blue or Gold.

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way that I can scale this to work on a list with many more objects inside the list and that it can work on more than 2 keywords like this list
`keywords=c("Blue", "Gold", "Red", "Purple")`?

Comment: Also, can you explain a little more of what this line `degree(Reduce(`+`, list_graph[blues]), mode = "in"))` does?

Comment: one other thing. Is it possible to do this without for loops?

Comment: @M76, sure, we could use `sapply` or something  similar, but that would only hurt readability and would be essentially the same thing. There are several reasons why this task can't really flow nicely in one or two lines: "Blue" or "Gold" are given by you (i.e., they aren't just directly names of some objects), so we must iterate over them; then we have to assign such columns names; graphs are special objects are there aren't hundreds of functions for them that are vectorized; and so on.